# Why my computer boot straight into Windows 7 and not boot options?

Tags: 12.04, windows

I just installed Ubuntu along side Windows 7, but when I turn on my computer it goes straight into Windows and doesn't recognize that I have Ubuntu installed. HELP!

Comment: If you could, update your question with some more relevant information like the model of your computer, whether your computer uses BIOS or UEFI and the installation method you used. That would make answering the question a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Okay:

1. You installed Ubuntu onto a secondary hard drive, or an external hardrive, or some other form of media different from your Windows Installation.

Answer: Change your boot options to put the place you installed Ubuntu as first priority over your Primary HDD.

I am guessing that would be the trouble.  If its not, reply and I will update my answer.